# How can I use \expandafter the expand the definition of this control sequence?

Tags: macros, expansion

I define a command `\test` that does nothing but define a control sequence `\c[count]`, where `[count]` is the current text value of the counter `count` at the time `\test` is executed.  I want `\c[count]` to output the text "Number `\thecount`", where `\thecount` should be the value of `count` at time of execution.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcounter{count}

\newcommand{\test}{\expandafter\def\csname c\thecount\endcsname{Number \thecount~}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{count}{1}
\test 
\setcounter{count}{2}
\test
\setcounter{count}{3}
\test

\csname c1\endcsname
\csname c2\endcsname
\csname c3\endcsname

\end{document}
```

This outputs:  "Number 3 Number 3 Number 3".  I believe this means that `\thecount` in the output of `\test` was not expanded during each `\test`.

How can I fix this to display "Number 1 Number 2 Number 3" as intended?  I'm unsure how to use `\expandafter` for this, my attempts keep breaking everything.  I relatively new to this sort of LaTeX, so I'd appreciate any help on this matter.

Comment: Replace the `\def` by `\edef`. You want the `\thecount` to be expanded at the time it's defined, otherwise `\thecount` will take the value of the counter at the time it's used

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see what happens.

1. The replacement text of a macro is absorbed with *no interpretation* or macro expansion during `\def`, except for the fact that explicit braces must be balanced, which is necessary for determining where the replacement text ends.
2. When `\csname` is being expanded, tokens are fully expanded until only unexpandable tokens remain, up to the matching `\endcsname`.

So, if you do `\def\foo{Number \thecount}`, the replacement text will contain `\thecount` which will be expanded after the expansion of `\foo` upon usage. What's the macro name is completely irrelevant.

To the contrary, if the value of `count` is 1, `\expandafter\def\csname foo\thecount\endcsname{whatever}` will define the macro with name “`foo1`” (that cannot be accessed unless using `\csname` or changing the category code of `1`).

Note that a single expansion step on `\thecount` will not produce `1`, but just

```
\@arabic\c@count
```

because LaTeX by default will do `\def\thecount{\@arabic\c@count}`, so a single `\expandafter` would not be sufficient: three expansion steps are necessary, because `\@arabic` is defined as

```
> \@arabic=macro:
#1->\number #1.
```

and so another step is necessary to get the value in Arabic numerals.

However, `\@arabic` is fully expandable, so you can use `\edef`:

```
\newcommand{\test}{\expandafter\edef\csname c\thecount\endcsname{Number \thecount~}}
```

because `\edef` is the same as `\def`, but the replacement text consists of the full expansion of the `<balanced text>` in the body of the definition.

Also

```
\newcommand{\test}{%
  \expandafter\def\csname c\thecount\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{%
    \expanded{Number \thecount~}%
  }%
}
```

would work, because the trailing `\expandafter` in `\csname` *is* expanded, triggering the expansion of `\expandafter` before `{`, which triggers the expansion of `\expanded`. Of course `\edef` is much simpler, but `\expanded` can be useful in other cases.

Be careful with `\edef` or `\expanded`, because “dangerous” tokens might need `\noexpand`.

Comment: Thank you!  This was very informative.